# Python: Cannot format SQL query string

Tags: python, mysql, string-formatting, pymysql

I want to create a SQL query string and execute it from python

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error


client = mysql.connector.connect(host=sql_host,
                                 port=sql_port,
                                 database=sql_db,
                                 user=os.environ['SQLUSER'],
                                 passwd=os.environ['SQLPASS']
                                 )
try:
    a = "val1"
    b = "val2"
    cursor = client.cursor()
    query = "insert into mytable values ('{}', '{}')".format(a,b)
    print(query)
    cursor.execute(query)

except Error as e:
    print(e)
```

This does not give me error but at the same time, nothing gets inserted in the table. I think thats because the query string that is created, looks like

`"insert into mytable values (\\'val1\\', \\'val2\\')"`

I have even tried `.replace('\\','')` but I cannot get the `\\`s removed from my query string.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

Thanks @cody for your help. But now, I am getting a different error

```
a = 'val1'
b = 'val2'
query = "insert into mytable values (%s, %s)"
print(query)
cursor.execute(query, (a,b))
client.commit()
```

Now i get

`1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1`

what does this mean? I dont even have any `''` in my values

**EDIT**

While investigating, I see that the `_executed` attribute of the `cursor` looks like this

```
'insert into dev_test_storage values (\\'val1\\', \\'val2\\')'
```

why do i still have `\\` in the query which gets executed?

Here is the create table statement

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myTable 
(
    col1 varchar(50) not null,
    col2 varchar (100) not null
);
```

Comment: You arent executing your query, you're executing nothing.

Comment: Your code doesn't show the query being passed to the cursor, can you add the traceback?

Comment: You should use query parameters instead of trying to glue values into your SQL string.

Comment: As @Loocid said, your execute call is empty.  You probably wanted `execute(query)` instead of just `execute()`.

Comment: sorry, just fixed that

Comment: Thanks. Can you add the entire trace as well? (Remove the try/except and paste in the error that is thrown)

Comment: please see the edit: `This does not give me error but at the same time, nothing gets inserted in the table`

Comment: Whenever you change the contents of a table (such as with an INSERT), you must COMMIT that change within the same session, or it is discarded.  Many database clients will do this step for you, but not all.  Do you know if the Polaris SQL client does autocommit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the following example in the MySQL [connector-python documentation for insert](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-transaction.html). Don't use `format` for your prepared statement parameters, instead pass them as the second argument to `execute`. The example shows passing the data both as a tuple and a dict:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='scott', database='employees')
cursor = cnx.cursor()

tomorrow = datetime.now().date() + timedelta(days=1)

add_employee = ("INSERT INTO employees "
               "(first_name, last_name, hire_date, gender, birth_date) "
               "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)")
add_salary = ("INSERT INTO salaries "
              "(emp_no, salary, from_date, to_date) "
              "VALUES (%(emp_no)s, %(salary)s, %(from_date)s, %(to_date)s)")

data_employee = ('Geert', 'Vanderkelen', tomorrow, 'M', date(1977, 6, 14))

# Insert new employee
cursor.execute(add_employee, data_employee)
emp_no = cursor.lastrowid

# Insert salary information
data_salary = {
  'emp_no': emp_no,
  'salary': 50000,
  'from_date': tomorrow,
  'to_date': date(9999, 1, 1),
}
cursor.execute(add_salary, data_salary)

# Make sure data is committed to the database
cnx.commit()

cursor.close()
cnx.close()
```

Additionally, you probably need to call `commit` as the documentation states

> Since by default Connector/Python turns autocommit off, and MySQL 5.5
>   and higher uses transactional InnoDB tables by default, it is
>   necessary to commit your changes using the connection's commit()
>   method. You could also roll back using the rollback() method.

**Edit:**

I'm not sure why you're still having issues with the query being improperly escaped, I've replicated your conditions as closely as possible and it works fine:

Table:

```
MariaDB [pets]> DESCRIBE myTable;
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| col1  | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| col2  | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Python code:

```
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='cody', password='secret', database='pets')
cursor = cnx.cursor()

a = 'val1'
b = 'val2'

query = "insert into myTable values (%s, %s)"

cursor.execute(query, (a,b))

cnx.commit()

print(cursor._executed)

cursor.close()
cnx.close()
```

The program runs successfully and prints the executed query as expected:

```
cody@servo:~$ python mysql-test.py
insert into myTable values ('val1', 'val2')
```

And the row is inserted:

```
MariaDB [pets]> SELECT * FROM myTable;
+------+------+
| col1 | col2 |
+------+------+
| val1 | val2 |
+------+------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: please see the latest update. I get a different error now `1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1`

Comment: I'm not sure what that could be, the only thing I see that's off is you should be caling `commit` on the connection object, not the cursor. What is the structure of `mytable`? Can you include the output of `DESCRIBE mytable`?

Comment: by the way, are you using python 3?

Comment: I'm stumped, I've tried to replicate your conditions as closely as possible and it works, see the edits to my answer. Can you post the entirety of the program you're running?

Comment: Yep, I'm running Python 3.5.3

Comment: i have python 2.7.11, maybe thats the problem. let me try upgrading to python 3